# Tracking API for Fedex and UPS

Tags: ups, fedex

Is there any JavaScript API available for tracking Fedex and UPS packages?

Comment: UPS has a SOAP API you can get reverse engineering the official app

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I googled for something like this but couldn't find anything. Then I decided to do it server side in ROR.

Here it is how to get UPS and Fedex `xml` request and response from their test servers.

### For Fedex:

```rb
track_no = '111111111111'  # This is a test tracking number

# This XML Request body for fedex
xml_req = 

"<TrackRequest xmlns='http://fedex.com/ws/track/v3'><WebAuthenticationDetail><UserCredential><Key>YOUR_ACC_KEY</Key>
                <Password>YOUR_ACC_PASSWORD</Password></UserCredential></WebAuthenticationDetail><ClientDetail>
                <AccountNumber>YOUR_ACC_NUMBER</AccountNumber><MeterNumber>YOUR_ACC_METER_NUMBER</MeterNumber></ClientDetail>
                <TransactionDetail><CustomerTransactionId>ActiveShipping</CustomerTransactionId></TransactionDetail>
                <Version><ServiceId>trck</ServiceId><Major>3</Major><Intermediate>0</Intermediate><Minor>0</Minor></Version>
                <PackageIdentifier><Value>#{track_no}</Value><Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type></PackageIdentifier>
                <IncludeDetailedScans>1</IncludeDetailedScans></TrackRequest>"

path = "https://gatewaybeta.fedex.com:443/xml"

#this url connects to the test server of fedex
# for live server url is:"https://gateway.fedex.com:443/xml"

url = URI.parse(path)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host,url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

response =  http.post(url.path, xml_req)
response_body = response.body
res = response_body.gsub(/<(\/)?.*?\:(.*?)>/, '<\1\2>')
hash = Hash.from_xml(res.to_s)
```

And that's it! You will get response in hash variable, I converted `xml` response in to Hash because we can easily use Hash object at our view to display response data.

### For UPS:

```rb
track_no = '1Z12345E1512345676'  # This is a test tracking number

# This XML Request body for UPS
xml_req = 

'<?xml version="1.0"?><AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US"><AccessLicenseNumber>YOUR_ACC_LICENCE_NUMBER</AccessLicenseNumber>
                    <UserId>YOUR_ACC_USER_ID</UserId><Password>YOUR_ACC_PASSWORD</Password></AccessRequest>
                    <?xml version="1.0"?><TrackRequest xml:lang="en-US"><Request><TransactionReference>
                    <CustomerContext>QAST Track</CustomerContext><XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion></TransactionReference>
                    <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction><RequestOption>activity</RequestOption></Request>
                    <TrackingNumber>#{track_no}</TrackingNumber></TrackRequest>'

path = "https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track"
url = URI.parse(path)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host,url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

response =  http.post(url.path, xml_req)
response_body = response.body
hash = Hash.from_xml(response_body.to_s)
```

This hash variable contains the response of UPS Tracking Request in Hash format.

Comment: Does this still work for Fedex?

Comment: Have you tried to work with UPS SCS AWBs?

Comment: I get an error "The XML document is well formed but the document is not valid" so perhaps this API has changed on the remote end.

Comment: It's not working now. How can I have a demo tracking number to test now?

Comment: how to get content in PHP?

Comment: For Fedex, this link will give new info: https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/ws/2014/dvg/WS_DVG_WebHelp/1_3_4_1_Example_Track_Request.htm

Comment: could you please give a sample php curl code for fedex tracking

Answer (score 21):

another easy way to do it: Just create a hyperlink with the following href

UPS:

http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_US&track.x=Track&trackNums=put_tracking_number_here

FEDEX:

http://fedex.com/Tracking?action=track&language=english&cntry_code=us&tracknumbers=put_tracking_number_here

(not as elegant, but quick, easy and gets the job done!)

Comment: and for usps   https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tLabels=<yourtrackingnumber>

Comment: @weather Access denied now. How can I have a demo tracking number to test now?

Comment: I can't get data of FedEx via API or curl. How can I get the content of tracking?

Comment: For FedEx Link: https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&action=track&language=english&cntry_code=us&tracknumbers=put_tracking_number_here for UPS use https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=put_tracking_number_here

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the [active_shipping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) gem for a nicer and cleaner way to track your packages for Fedex and UPS