# UPS Test Tracking Numbers (is there a such thing?)

Tags: api, soap, soap-client, ups

I finally got the UPS tracking API to work. Or atleast I think I do. It is giving me a 'invalid tracking number' response. My problem right now is I have no packages to track. Does anyone know of any resources that allow me to test fake orders from UPS, or anything that will give a response ? Thanks

I am using the UPS Tracking Developers Kit and need package resposnes.

Comment: 1Z12345E1512345676
from here: [Tracking API][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879953/tracking-api-for-fedex-and-ups

Comment: That number or is not longer working http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_US&track.x=Track&trackNums=1Z12345E1512345676

Answer (score 14):

Here's an update in case someone comes across this as I did.

The below data is taken from the *Tracking Web Service Developer Guide **(January 9, 2017)***.

You should be able to access it from the [UPS Developer Kit](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource) download page. There's a section called `Download the API` with a link to download [Tracking.zip](https://www.ups.com/gec/techdocs/pdf/Tracking.zip). The developer guide is located at `Tracking.zip\Tracking\Developers Guide\Tracking Web Service Developer Guide.pdf` The table is located on page 7.

```
"Type","Value","Option","Service","Response"
"Tracking","1Z12345E0205271688\n(Signature Availability)","Activity (All)","2nd Day Air","Delivered"
"Tracking","1Z12345E6605272234","None (Last)","World Wide Express","Delivered"
"Shipping","1Z12345E0305271640\n(Second Package:\n1Z12345E0393657226)","None (Last)","Ground","Delivered"
"Tracking","1Z12345E1305277940","None (Last)","Next Day Air Saver","ORIGIN SCAN"
"Tracking","1Z12345E6205277936","Activity (All)","Next Day Air Saver","2nd Delivery attempt"
"Tracking","1Z12345E020527079","None (Last)",,"Invalid Tracking Number"
"Tracking","1Z12345E1505270452","None (Last)",,"No Tracking Information Available"
"Tracking",990728071,"Activity (All)","UPS Freight LTL","In Transit"
"Tracking",3251026119,"Activity (All)",,"Delivered Origin CFS"
"MI Tracking Number",9102084383041101186729,"None (Last)",,
"MI Reference Number","cgish000116630","None (Last)",,
"Tracking","1Z648616E192760718","Activity","UPS Worldwide Express Freight","Order Process by UPS"
"Tracking",5548789114,"Activity","UPS Express Freight","Response for UPS Air Freight"
"Tracking","ER751105042015062","Activity","UPS Ocean","Response for UPS Ocean Freight"
"Tracking","1ZWX0692YP40636269","Activity","UPS SUREPOST","Response for UPS SUREPOST"
```

Hope that helps the next person to come along :)

Comment: https://www.ups.com/us/en/services/technology-integration/developer-api.page is up to date url

Comment: @alain.janinm not anymore; it's 404 now

Answer (score 9):

You can use production tracking numbers on the UPS test environment. Moreover, on the ***Appendix H*** of the ***Tracking Web Service Developers Guide (December 31, 2012)***, you can find a list of tracking numbers that can be useful if you want see tracking numbers with different set of information like *proof of delivery*.

Best!

Comment: If only the API guides were better documented.

Comment: I have to agree. Sadly UPS API documentation is not the best.

Comment: Because the website changed, I guess the best way to find the documentation over the time will be to search for "developer kit" in search bar to be redirected on up to date pages.

Answer (score 6):

These were taken from the July 11, 2016, UPS Tracking Tracking Web Service Developer Guide, pg. 13.

```
TRACKING NUMBER, SERVICE, RESPONSE
1Z12345E0205271688 (Signature Availability), 2nd Day Air, Delivered
1Z12345E6605272234, World Wide Express, Delivered
1Z12345E0305271640, (Second Package: 1Z12345E0393657226), Ground, Delivered
1Z12345E1305277940, Next Day Air Saver, ORIGIN SCAN
1Z12345E6205277936, Day Air Saver, 2nd Delivery attempt
1Z12345E020527079, Invalid Tracking Number
1Z12345E1505270452, No Tracking Information Available
990728071, UPS Freight LTL, In Transit
3251026119, Delivered Origin CFS
MI Tracking Number: 9102084383041101186729
MI Reference Number: cgish000116630
1Z648616E192760718, UPS Worldwide Express Freight, Order Process by UPS
5548789114, UPS Express Freight, Response for UPS Air Freight
ER751105042015062, UPS Ocean, Response for UPS Ocean Freight
1ZWX0692YP40636269, UPS SUREPOST, Response for UPS SUREPOST
```

Comment: Can you reference the webpage where you retrieved the guide, please?

Comment: All codes are outdated, details are only available for shipments made within the last 120 days.

Comment: @jsickles I'm 3 years late, but here you go: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US

Also, stay in 2017