# Generate fedex label

Tags: php, fedex

I am trying to integrate fedex service on my site where user purchase products and selects fedex shipping method, i am able to calculate the shipping rates with help of api but i also want to generate a code/label which can be used further to track orders like when a user purchase a item he/she will get a tracking code generated by fedex.
is it possible with php and is there api or code available.
my shopping cart is in custom php code and not using any plugin.

Answer (score 3):

FedEx does have a ShipService API that allows you to create a label. You send the info to the service, and it returns the label in a few different formats, PDF/PNG/ZPL.

Comment: Can you please refer a link or tutorial for API usage, i didnt found any good tutorial to integrate it. i am using php.

Comment: When you go to the FedEx developer site, you can download sample code in different formats (Java,C#,PHP). Once in the site, look at the FedEx Web Services area, you'll see a tab for the Documentation/Downloads. In that section, look at the Advanced Services tab, then the Create Shipment section.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Shippo's multi-carrier shipping API. Check out the overview guide [here](http://goshippo.com/api). It allows you immediate access to 14+ shipping carriers including FedEx. Shippo also has heavily discounted USPS Priority Mail rates.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a FedEx API key already? If not, you could try using a [shipping API](http://easypost.com) like EasyPost to manage everything through 1 API.

Otherwise, you'll have to make an XML request of the FedEx API which you can do as per this answer - [Tracking API for Fedex and UPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879953/tracking-api-for-fedex-and-ups)

Comment: above mentioned is for package tracking not for lable and tracking number creation